# How to use multi_query with DELETE / UPDATE only?

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-delete, multi-query

When I was using multi_query with SELECT, it looked like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT....';
$sql .= 'SELECT....';
...

if ($db->multi_query($sql))
{ 
    do
    {
        if ($stmt = $db->store_result())
        {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
            {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                {
                    $var[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
        }
    } while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());
}
```

But how should it look when I need DELETE or UPDATE only, since there are no results?

```
$sql = 'DELETE...';
$sql .= 'DELETE...';
$sql .= 'UPDATE...';

if ($db->multi_query($sql))
{
    do
    {
        /*well.. nothing?*/
    }
    while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());
}
```

seems to work, even without the `do {...}`, but isn't there a better / clean solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember you are on the right way of executing multiple updates. The one thing you seem to miss is checking for errors . For instance (from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)),

```
if ($db->multi_query($sql))
{
  do
  {
  // do nothing, just iterate over results to make sure no errors  
  }
  while ($db->next_result());
}
if ($db->errno) {
    //error handling
}
```

Comment: You're right, I should check for errors.. that's also on my list of improvements :) But first of all I was trying to remove unnecessary code, improve queries etc., so I came to the question if an empty `do {...} while` loop is the right way here

Comment: I think so. Otherwise, you cannot check if all queries in the batch completed without errors ("Returns FALSE if the first statement failed. To retrieve subsequent errors from other statements you have to call mysqli_next_result() first." -  multi_query documentation)

Comment: That's true.. but is the `do { ... }` part necessary here? `while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());` only seems to work too, but looks a bit strange.. same for `while ($db->more_results()) { $db->next_result(); }` .. or did I miss something?